# notify instances by events

Tags: c#, events

I think what I'm trying to do is very simple but I can't manage to

I have a static event somewhere in a class A:

```
public static event Action OnInvalidated;
```

that I call when my data is invalidated.
When I instanciate a new class of type B, I want to do the following:

```
A.OnInvalidated+= () => this.RefreshColumns();
```

Basically I want to call RefreshColumns on every instance registered when OnInvalidated fires.

This compiles fine, but how can I remove the lambda function when I dispose of my object?
I think that doing

```
 A.OnInvalidated-= () => this.RefreshColumns();
```

Will not work, and I can't declare

```
Action myAction = () => this.RefreshColumns();
```

as a function member either

Comment: What error do you get when trying to compile the second line?

Comment: "this" not available in current context

Comment: @lezebulon Where, exactly, do you have that code?  It can't be in a static method or static constructor...

Comment: @Reed Copsey : I edited my first post, the question is actually a bit different

Comment: it is difficult to un-subscribe when using anonymous handlers

Comment: @Yoztastic : the problem is that I don't know how to create the same handler as a member object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, instead of doing:

```
A.OnInvalidated+= () => this.RefreshColumns();
```

Just assign the method directly (notice the `()` are missing and also the lambda declaration):

```
A.OnInvalidated += this.RefreshColumns;
```

Then when you unsubscribe you just do:

```
A.OnInvalidated -= this.RefreshColumns;
```

I think the problem is that you are introducing this anonymous lambda when you don't need to, making it more difficult to unsubscribe the method.

Answer (score 2):

Try it as follows:

```
class A : IDisposable
{
    public static event Action OnInvalidated;

    public A()
    {
        A.OnInvalidated +=  this.SomeMethod();
        A.OnInvalidated +=  this.SomeOtherMethod();
    }

        public void Dispose()
        {
        A.OnInvalidated -=  this.SomeMethod();
        A.OnInvalidated -=  this.SomeOtherMethod();
        }

    public SomeMethod()
    {

    }

    public SomeOtherMethod()
    {

    }
}
```

Note that it is important to implement IDisposable and unsubscribe all static events in Dispose() if you want to avoid memory leaks. Otherwise subscribers of static events will never be garbage collected since the event maintains a reference to the object.

Comment: This can't be right.  `B` is what is subscribing to `A`, not `A` to itself.  I also believe that `B` is what implements `IDisposable` here.

Comment: for that case replace 'A' in "class A" and "public A()" by 'B'

Comment: .. and also move the event `OnInvalidated` to a separate class `A`.